# ios - Can't generate new APN cert - the option is disabled

Tags: ios, iphone, apn

I received an email saying "Your Apple Push Notification Service Certificate will expire in 30 days". So I went to the dev portal to create a new APN cert. However, when I logged in the APN generation option was disabled:

[image]

Any idea why/how to fix this?

Comment: I don't the reason of your problem, but can you try generating it another way? Go to MemberCenter, then select Identifiers, select your AppID and you will see there the "Edit" button. After clicking the button scroll down to Push notifications section and there should be  "Create certificate" buttons for both cases - Development and Production. Generating a new certificate does not revoke the old one automatically as I remember correctly.

Comment: Yeah! That worked. This seems a bug of the dev portal to me but anyway, it worked. Thanks for the quick and precise answer!